# JavaFX FXML Label doesn't update its value

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to update a label from another controller, yet it won't update visually.

The following controller controls dynamically loads the external controller.

```
private ClientShowController clientShowController; 

public void initialize(){ 

    try { 
        pane_clientDetail.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../resources/Client_show.fxml")));
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../resources/Client_show.fxml")); 
        loader.load(); 

        clientShowController = (ClientShowController) loader.getController(); 
        System.out.println(clientShowController);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 

private void showPersonDetails(Person person) {
    if (person != null) { 
        //Update 
        clientShowController.setId(Integer.toString(person.getId()));
    }
}
```

The second controller:

```
@FXML private Label lbl_id;    

public void setId(String strId){
    System.out.println(strId);
    lbl_id.setText(strId);
    System.out.println(lbl_id);
}
```

Note that:

- The System.out is correctly displaying the id on the label;
- The second controller is tied to an FXML file that is embedded in the first one. As the code shows, the second FXML file / controller is dynamically loaded: `pane_clientDetail.getChildren().add()`.
- When setting the id from the initialize method in the second controller, the id is displayed in the label as expected:

  public void initialize(){
      this.setId("12");
  }

Edit:

The first (main) FXML defines:

```
<Pane fx:id="pane_clientDetail"/>
```

This pane is declared as property

```
@FXML private Pane pane_clientDetail;
```

The second:

```
<GridPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.controllers.ClientShowController">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="144.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="102.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="195.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="195.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Label text="given name" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="10.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Label>
      <Label text="family name" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="10.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Label>
      <Label text="gender" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="10.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Label>
      <Label text="email" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="10.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Label>
      <Label text="phone" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="10.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Label>
      <Label text="id">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="10.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Label>
      <Label text="address" GridPane.rowIndex="6">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="10.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Label>
      <Label text="zip" GridPane.rowIndex="7">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="10.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="lbl_id" text="-" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="lbl_given_name" text="-" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Label fx:id="lbl_family_name" text="-" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <Label fx:id="lbl_gender" text="-" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
      <Label fx:id="lbl_email" text="-" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
      <Label fx:id="lbl_phone" text="-" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
      <Label fx:id="lbl_address" text="-" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
      <Label fx:id="lbl_zip" text="-" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
      <Label text="city" GridPane.rowIndex="8">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets left="10.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="lbl_city" text="-" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
   </children>
   <VBox.margin>
      <Insets top="10.0" />
   </VBox.margin>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: Can you add the definition of the fxml as well? What do you mean by embedded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have two instances of UI:

```
1. pane_clientDetail.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../resources/Client_show.fxml")));

2. FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../resources/Client_show.fxml"));
```

You first load a view and attach it to `pane_clientDetail` and this is the view that is being shown. Then you create another one and obtain controller to it. For obvious reasons 2nd controller won't update 1st view.

Solution:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../resources/Client_show.fxml"));
Parent view = loader.load();
pane_clientDetail.getChildren().add(view);
// rest of the code
```